# Audio and Generated Video Keeps Desyncing Despite Audio Being 48000khz

Tags: c++, audio, video

So I'm writing a C++ program that will take a wav file, generate a visualization, and export the video out alongside the audio using ffmpeg (pipe). I've been able to get output out to ffmpeg just fine and a video with the visualization and audio are created by ffmpeg.

The problem is the video and audio are desyncing. The video is just too fast and ends before the song is completed (the video file is the correct length; the waveform just flatlines and ends, indicating that ffmpeg reached the end of the video and is just using the last frame it received until the audio ends). So I'm not sending enough frames to ffmpeg.

Below is a truncated version of the source code:

```
// Example code
int main()
{
    // LoadAudio();
    
    uint32_t frame_max = audio.sample_rate / 24; // 24 frames per second
    uint32_t frame_counter = 0;
    
    // InitializePipe2FFMPEG();
    
    // (Left channel and right channel are always equal in size)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < audio.left_channel.size(); ++i)
    {
        // UpdateWaveform4Image();
        
        if (frame_counter % frame_max == 0)
        {
            // DrawImageAndSend2Pipe();
            
            frame_counter = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ++frame_counter;
        }
    }
    
    // FlushAndClosePipe();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The commented-out functions are fake and irrelevant. I know this because "UpdateWaveform4Image()" updates the waveform used to generate the image every sample. (I know that's inefficient, but I'll worry about optimization later.) The waveform is a std::vector in which each element stores the y-coordinate of each sample. It has no effect on when the program will generate a new frame for the video.

Also ffmpeg is set to output 24 frames per second--trust me, I thought that was the problem too because by default ffmpeg outputs to 25 fps.

My line of thinking for the modulus check is that frame_counter is incremented every sample. frame_max equals 2000 because 48000 / 24 = 2000. I know the audio is clocked at 48kHz because I created the file myself. So it SHOULD generate a new image every 2000 samples.

Here is a link to the output video: [[output]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12OIWOjd-KCRO4NAeRaOpK49U0eKKjK6N/view)

Any advice would be helpful.

EDIT: Skip to 01:24 to see the waveform flatline.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your problem yourself? The code is clearly too complicated to show the code here. In the process of making the code simple enough to show on Stack Overflow, you might discover the problem.

Comment: What do you think I've been doing? I'm just asking about the math. The rendering of the video has no bearing on anything.

Comment: How many frames does your program output, and how many audio samples?

Comment: The program outputs 24 fps, and ffmpeg is set to receive 24 fps (not just output!). As mentioned before, the sample rate is 48,000. ffmpeg receives, for this audio file, about 2,208 frames total, but I'm only calculating that from the audio length. 4,416,000 samples total for the audio.

Comment: I didn't ask how many you think it should produce, I asked how many it did produce. And not per second, either.

Comment: If you check how many frames and how many samples the program outputs, and there is not a ratio of 2000 samples per frame, then you will know something is wrong with your program's math. If there are 2000 samples per frame, then something is wrong with ffmpeg.